# Modalview information from another viewcontrol

Tags: ios, properties, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to send label data from one `viewcontrol` to be presented in another view control.

The code sends the info from the button, what I need to understand is how to send the Label info.

Opens the modal:

```
-(IBAction) showModal:(id)sender {
    outputLabel.text=@"Nothing Chosen";
    [[(ContentViewController *)self.parentViewController outputLabel] 
     setText:[sender currentTitle]];

switch (transitionStyle.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        modalContent.modalTransitionStyle=
        UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        break;
        }
[self presentModalViewController:modalContent animated:YES];
}
```

Received the modal back:

```
-(IBAction) hideModal:(id)sender {
      outputLabel2.text=@"12" ;
    [[(Corina3ViewController *)self.parentViewController outputLabel] 
     setText:[sender currentTitle]];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   

}
```

I want to send the label info to the model. The label is "clearbLabel".

Comment: It's difficult to understand the controller flow here. Both methods don't seem to be in the same controller based on what you're casting the parent view controller to. Can you describe your problem a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a label object in your modalView and set it at the `- showModal:` method

modalView:

```
// @interface
UILabel *clearLabel
// don't forget to @synthesize
```

```
-(IBAction) showModal:(id)sender {
    // your code;
    [modalView setClearLabel: clearLabel];
}
```

You can even nil it out after:

```
-(IBAction) hideModal:(id)sender {
    // your code;
    [modalView setClearLabel: nil];
}
```

Comment: You didn't add the @property line